# How to recycle two colours in a geom_jitter with more than 2 categories

Tags: ggplot2, colors

I would like to use only two colours that alternate in a `geom_jitter` plot.

```
  ggplot(data=dat1, aes(name, value, colour=factor(location)))+
      geom_jitter()
```

The `location` has more than 2 categories, but I want to colour them by alternating two colours.
So far I've tried to add `+ scale_color_manual(values=rep(c("red","green")))` but that did not work.

My data is something like this

```
ID <- c('P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4')
location <- c('harm', 'breast', 'colon', 'liver')
value <- c(7.2, 5.4, 0.3, 2.1)

ID location   value
p1  harm       7.2
p2  breast     5.4 
p3  colon      0.3
p4  liver      2.1
```

What I want is the plot shows only two colours eg. harm = red, breast=green, colon = red .... I can't do manually because I have a lot of categories and I want to create a function in which the location may be different.

Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some of your data? You can just edit your question and paste in the results of `dput(head(dat1))`.

Comment: can you kindly elaborate what you mean with alternating colors? a picture with a desired output will help

Comment: Hi, yes I did. Hopefully is clear now

Answer (score 0):

you can add the numbers of your categories at the end. E.G if you have 32 categories:

```
scale_color_manual(values=rep(c("blue","red"), 32 ))
```